# Правильное размещение блоков (для респонсив)

Tags: html, responsive

Знатоки, подскажите, как правильно сделать позиционирование блоков, чтобы при разных разрешениях между ними была пропорциональная ширина?
[Вот то, что получилось у меня](http://dev.landingpage.club/free1/)

[image: Скриншот]

Я сделал
float:left блокам;
задал ширину, высоту в VW;
margin-right: 3vw;
margin-left:auto;
Но на разных разрешениях блоки ведут себя не предсказуемо. Как правильно делать? Медиазапросы для каждых 100 пикселей делать или как-то иначе?

Comment: так вы посмотрите как на том сайте сделано, и когда у вас ломается смотрите почему там не ломается

Comment: так это я показал то, что я сделал. это моя верстка на тест-сервере

Comment: хочу знать, как нужно делать правильно, а не костылями, лишь бы работало...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте для каждого блока margin левый и правый одинаковые. Потом задайте для элемента `section` ширину в **vw** по схеме:

```
  (ширина блока + 2 х margin левый) х количество блоков в строке
```

Если дизайн адаптивный, рассчитайте ширину `section` для каждого варианта стиля (если в разных вариантах предусмотрено изменение количества блоков в строке).

**UPD**

Другой вариант, так как в выше представленном варианте между блоками удвоенный пробел (хотя его можно уменьшить в 2 раза и все будет как требуется, если для блока просто задать `margin: 1.5vw;`):

В этом варианте для блоков прописываем `margin: 1.5vw 0 1.5vw 3vw;`, а ширину `section` высчитываем по формуле:

```
 (ширина блока + левый margin блока) х количество блоков в строке + левый margin блока
```

То есть для двух блоков в строке шириной 25vw получаем ширину `section`:

```
 (25 + 3) х 2 + 3 = 59vw
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Вот не могу понять, а зачем еще 
"...) х количество блоков в строке **+ левый margin блока**..."
зачем добавляем + 3vw?

Comment: @Игорь Мандич, чтобы справа от правого крайнего блока в строке был такой же отступ как и слева от левого крайнего. Блоки же влево прижимаются из-за float: left;

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь функцией calc() в css3. Например, у вас ширина блока 20vw, тогда делаем так

```
.block {
margin-right: calc(100vw / 4 - 20vw * 4 / 3);
}
.block:nth-child(4n) {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Если укажете значения в %, будет тоже прекрасно работать